# What are recommended SSH key settings?

Tags: ssh, encryption

I was reading over the [algoritms used in SSH](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_09.htm) and I'm trying to figure out which one is the current "recommended" or at least which target audience each is for.

- Should I make sure my SSH key is 1.0 compatible?
- Should I use 1024 bit or 2048? Is 2048 twice as slow?
- Are some better for sensitive uses - while others are for constant data transmission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use [1024 RSA key](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/006.pdf). Use 2048 or 4096. RSA use only for authentication. Data encrypted with symmetric algorithm(AES, Blowfish, 3DES) with other key. There are no performance differences between 1024 and 2048 key.

> Should I make sure my SSH key is 1.0 compatible

Generate RSA keys. You can use the RSA keys for SSH protocol 1 and 2 versions. DSA keys for use only SSH protocol version 2.

Comment: What do you mean "Data encrypted ... with other key". Are you talking about creating two key pairs? One for login - and the other for data transfer? If so, how would you do that? I though that SSH just used one key. I don't think I need SSH 1.0 for anything so should I use 2048 DSA?

Comment: RSA encrypt authentication and key exchange. Data transfer key generate before data transfer and key length does not depend on RSA key.

Comment: Just for the people which don't want to read the man page of `ssh-keygen`. To generate an 4096 bit RSA key use: `ssh-keygen -Z rsa -b 4096`

Answer (score 1):

I'll just second ooshro on the cryptography (RSA is used only for key exchange and therefore cheap, I recommend RSA-2048 or above). After that, the encryption ciphers are quite cheap on modern hardware.

On the protocol: just avoid SSH-1, which has some weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

I'll third ooshro and recommend setting a password for the private key as well. It's really not much of a hassle to enter a password for it on the order of once per day, and if your private key is compromised, not all is lost.